# Random extraction from a list with NO REPLACEMENT

Tags: r, list, random, extract

So I am wondering how to extract randomly a string from a list in R with NO REPLACEMENT till the list is empty.
To write

`sample(x, size=1, replace=FALSE)`

is not helping me, since string are extracted more than once before the list gets empty.

Kind regards

Comment: Please provide a small sample dataset that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration one list element will be picked, and from this element a value removed. If there is only one value left, the list element is removed.

```
x <- list(a = "bla", b = c("ble", "bla"), c = "bli")
while (length(x) > 0) {
  s <- sample(x, size = 1)
  column <- x[[names(s)]]
  value <- sample(unlist(s, use.names = FALSE), size = 1)

  list_element_without_value <- subset(column, column != value)

  x[[names(s)]] <- if (length(list_element_without_value) == 0) {
    NULL
  } else {
    list_element_without_value
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I meant. thank you very much! I solved the issue with a different and less fancy code, next time I will check this out!

Answer (score 0):

```
sample(x)
```

You can't use size=1 on repeated calls and expect it to know not to grab values previously selected. You have to grab all the values you want at one time. This code will shuffle your data and then you can grab the first element when you need it. Then the next time you need something grab the second... And so on.

Comment: Yes you are right and I knew that. My point was then trying to remove extracted value but I fail since the list is a vector and with 'which' from plyr I could not subsetting saying which(x$column name != "Extracted value"). Any tip?

Comment: My tip is asking why are you doing it that way in the first place? Why not just shuffle the list and then pick off the values that you want in order?